# How to use anotation instead of HttpSecurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring boot app with OAuth2. I want to open a few endpoints for anonymous access. I can do it using:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/xyz/**").anonymous()
          .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

but is there any way to do it more selectively and open only specific endpoints by putting some annotations there? I tried `@PermitAll` but it still requires authentication.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, because Spring Boot has a default web security, which authenticates every request. So you need to change/override web security, see [Spring Boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security).

Comment: Removed my answer `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` as it doesn't work. I will try to find something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can use antMatchers("/YOUR_ENDOINT/**").permitAll();

Comment: OP's question is *How to use anotation instead of HttpSecurity?* Your solution has no anotation and is more or less the same as OP's `.antMatchers("/xyz/**").anonymous()`.